# EnterCriticalSection Deadlocking

Tags: c++, timer, deadlock, sleep, critical-section

I found some code that claimed to be able to make a thread sleep for an accurate amount of time. Testing the code out, it seems to work great, however it always deadlocks after a short amount of time.

Here is the original code. I put prints before entering and leaving the critical section, and saw that sometimes it leaves or enters twice in a row. It seems to deadlock at the EnterCriticalSection call within the Wait function.

Is there a way I can modify this code to retain its functionality while not deadlocking?

```cpp
//----------------------------------------------------------------
class PreciseTimer
{
public:
   PreciseTimer() : mRes(0), toLeave(false), stopCounter(-1)
   {
      InitializeCriticalSection(&crit);
      mRes = timeSetEvent(1, 0, &TimerProc, (DWORD)this,
                          TIME_PERIODIC);
   }
   virtual ~PreciseTimer()
   {
      mRes = timeKillEvent(mRes);
      DeleteCriticalSection(&crit);
   }

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Function name   : Wait
   // Description     : Waits for the required duration of msecs.
   //                 : Timer resolution is precisely 1 msec
   // Return type     : void  :
   // Argument        : int timeout : timeout in msecs
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   void Wait(int timeout)
   {
      if ( timeout )
      {
         stopCounter = timeout;
         toLeave = true;
         // this will do the actual delay - timer callback shares
         // same crit section
         EnterCriticalSection(&crit);
         LeaveCriticalSection(&crit);
      }
   }
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Function name   : TimerProc
   // Description     : Timer callback procedure that is called
   //                 : every 1msec
   //                 : by high resolution media timers
   // Return type     : void CALLBACK  :
   // Argument        : UINT uiID :
   // Argument        : UINT uiMsg :
   // Argument        : DWORD dwUser :
   // Argument        : DWORD dw1 :
   // Argument        : DWORD dw2 :
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   static void CALLBACK TimerProc(UINT uiID, UINT uiMsg, DWORD
                                  dwUser, DWORD dw1, DWORD dw2)
   {
      static volatile bool entered = false;

      PreciseTimer* pThis = (PreciseTimer*)dwUser;
      if ( pThis )
      {
         if ( !entered && !pThis->toLeave )   // block section as
                                              // soon as we can
         {
            entered = true;
            EnterCriticalSection(&pThis->crit);
         }
         else if ( pThis->toLeave && pThis->stopCounter == 0 )
                                              // leave section
                                              // when counter
                                              // has expired
         {
            pThis->toLeave = false;
            entered = false;
            LeaveCriticalSection(&pThis->crit);
         }
         else if ( pThis->stopCounter > 0 )   // if counter is set
                                              // to anything, then
                                              // continue to drop
                                              // it...
            --pThis->stopCounter;
      }
   }

private:
   MMRESULT         mRes;
   CRITICAL_SECTION crit;
   volatile bool    toLeave;
   volatile int     stopCounter;
};
```

Comment: How do you use this to cause the deadlock?

Comment: Sorry, the only function in this class is Wait, and calling it causes a deadlock after a short random amount of time

Comment: But to call Wait() you have to have an object.  How do you create that object?  Show your `main` function.

Comment: After leaving the CS, if the timer callback is called again before the waiting thread can enter the CS - 1 ms is a fairly small window -  the timer will enter the CS again and the program will deadlock.

Comment: As Remy's answer indicates, there is no protection to `pThis->stopCounter`. So if the CPU is busy for any reason and a `TimerProc` executes before the previous call to `TimerProc` ends, `--pThis->stopCounter` can execute twice, and make `pThis->stopCounter` becomes a negative number while `pThis->toLeave` is true. Then `LeaveCriticalSection` never gets called.

Answer (score 4):

A deadlock in `EnterCriticalSection()` usually means that another thread called `EnterCriticalSection()` but never called `LeaveCriticalSection()`.

As shown, this code is not very thread-safe (and `timeSetEvent()` is a threaded timer). If multiple `PreciseTimer` timers are running at the same time, they are using the same `TimerProc()` callback, and thus are sharing the same `entered` variable without protecting it from concurrent access.  And if multiple threads call `Wait()` on the same `PreciseTimer` object at the same time, they are going to step over each other's use of the `stopCounter` and `toLeave` members, which are also not protected them from concurrent access.  Even a single thread calling `Wait()` on a single `PreciseTimer` is not safe since `TimerProc()` runs in its own thread and `stopCounter` is not adequately protected.

This code is full of race conditions.

Comment: Good answer. The code is really a mess. I also do not see a guarantee to make the `EnterCriticalSection` in `Wait` execute after the `EnterCriticalSection` call in `TimerProc`. So the wait may not happen at all. The accuracy setting of the timer may also be a big battery drainer.